# What is the keyboard shortcut which displays the pop up emoji modal on a Mac?

Tags: emoji

What is the keyboard shortcut which displays the pop up emoji modal on a Mac?

[image: Emoji Pop Up]

Comment: I was asked this question many times.  I know it is a simple and maybe stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the web, so I hope this is helpful 

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold `control ^` + `command ⌘` keys, then press the `spacebar` key.